# Update Int Field

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Why is my table not getting updated?  For example, if I run this statement alone, I have a value of 6 returned

```
Select COUNT(*)
from #madeupland
where SOapproved IS NULL
```

however, when it is run within my entire statement it returns 0 as the table is not updated.  Did I use an incorrect `set` or `update` statement here?

```
Declare @numapproved int, @totalnumpending int, @nummanpending int, @numsopending int

Create Table #madeupland
(
    RamaldaID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,cofeetypes varchar(50)
    ,mangerapproved varchar(10)
    ,SOapproved varchar(10)
    ,numapproved int
    ,totalnumpending int
    ,nummanpending int
    ,numsopending int
)

Insert Into #madeupland (cofeetypes, mangerapproved, soapproved) Values
('Black', 'Yes', NULL), ('Black', NULL, NULL), ('Black', 'Yes', NULL),
('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL)

Update #madeupland
Set @numapproved = (Select COUNT(*) 
                    from #madeupland
                    Where mangerapproved is not null
                    And SOapproved is not null)
,@totalnumpending = (Select COUNT(*) 
                   From #madeupland
                   Where mangerapproved is null
                   and SOapproved is null)
,@nummanpending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       From #madeupland
                       where mangerapproved is null)
,@numsopending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       from #madeupland
                       where SOapproved IS NULL)

Select * from #madeupland
DROP TABLE #madeupland
```

Comment: Why are you updating for example @numapproved and not numapproved?

Comment: @Lennart - well that would explain it.  Simply remove the @ symbol fixed my issue.  Thank you for pointing out my simple mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work.

You should keep some error handling in your code using `try.. catch` unless you are doing this for educational purpose only.

```
Declare @numapproved int, @totalnumpending int, @nummanpending int, @numsopending int

Create Table #madeupland
(
    RamaldaID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,cofeetypes varchar(50)
    ,mangerapproved varchar(10)
    ,SOapproved varchar(10)
    ,numapproved int
    ,totalnumpending int
    ,nummanpending int
    ,numsopending int
)

Insert Into #madeupland (cofeetypes, mangerapproved, soapproved) Values
('Black', 'Yes', NULL), ('Black', NULL, NULL), ('Black', 'Yes', NULL),
('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL)


Set @numapproved = (Select COUNT(*) 
                    from #madeupland
                    Where mangerapproved is not null
                    And SOapproved is not null)
Set @totalnumpending = (Select COUNT(*) 
                   From #madeupland
                   Where mangerapproved is null
                   and SOapproved is null)
Set @nummanpending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       From #madeupland
                       where mangerapproved is null)
Set @numsopending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       from #madeupland
                       where SOapproved IS NULL)

-- select @numapproved, @totalnumpending, @nummanpending, @numsopending

 Update #madeupland
 set numapproved = @numapproved,
        totalnumpending = @totalnumpending,
        nummanpending = @nummanpending,
        numsopending = @numsopending

Select * from #madeupland
DROP TABLE #madeupland
```

Actually, you dont need the variables at all

```
Create Table #madeupland
(
    RamaldaID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,cofeetypes varchar(50)
    ,mangerapproved varchar(10)
    ,SOapproved varchar(10)
    ,numapproved int
    ,totalnumpending int
    ,nummanpending int
    ,numsopending int
)

Insert Into #madeupland (cofeetypes, mangerapproved, soapproved) Values
('Black', 'Yes', NULL), ('Black', NULL, NULL), ('Black', 'Yes', NULL),
('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL), ('Medium', NULL, NULL)

Update #madeupland
Set numapproved = (Select COUNT(*) 
                    from #madeupland
                    Where mangerapproved is not null
                    And SOapproved is not null)
,totalnumpending = (Select COUNT(*) 
                   From #madeupland
                   Where mangerapproved is null
                   and SOapproved is null)
,nummanpending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       From #madeupland
                       where mangerapproved is null)
,numsopending = (Select COUNT(*)
                       from #madeupland
                       where SOapproved IS NULL)

Select * from #madeupland
DROP TABLE #madeupland
```